# How to handle SSO in Selenium Java with cucumber framework

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, selenium-java

How to handle SSO in Selenium Java with cucumber framework. Can anybody tells me what is the process of doing it?

Comment: Need more information. What type of SSO you are having?

Comment: AzureAD SSO for Windchill web application. We are automating the test cases for windchill. Recently our WIndchill is configured with SSO. So need to configure selenium with SSO for accessing Windchill